# How to include js file in a module which depend on jquery?

Tags: javascript

I have a module called **catalog_menu**

I included a js file within this module in this way:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'catalog_menu') . '/js/catalog_menu.js');
```

Now in the browser I get this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
```

I think that the problem is that catalogo_menu.js is loaded before jquery.js (the jquery library)

What is the right way to load a js file which depends on jquery library?

Comment: Are you using Drupal 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually think it is pretty unlikely that you have a weight problem, unless you redefined your module to have a extremely low weight.  Make sure you have JS optimization turned off, and then do a view source and make sure jQuery is the first script loaded (nearly always is).

My two *guesses* are

1. You have a JS error somewhere else, and this is a weird side effect.
2. You have a JS error in your `catalog_menu.js` (or another file) that is nuking the `$` object by accident.

Also, you should you use an anonymous closure or [JS module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) for code, because Drupa 7 defaults jQuery no-conflict mode.

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  function init () {
    $("body").addClass("catalog-menu");
  }

  Drupal.behaviors.catalog_menu = {
    attach: init
  };
}(jQuery, Drupal));
```

Comment: I tried just leaving these lines: (but not working at all, not error message neither)

Comment: (function ($, Drupal) {

 
 function init () {
   $('.logo-img').hide();
  }

  Drupal.behaviors.catalog_menu = {
    attach: init
  };
 
 
}(jQuery, Drupal));

Answer (score 0):

You can change your module's weight to ensure it gets loaded after everything else.

Several ways :

- SQL the system table (`update system set weight=9999 where name = 'mymodule'`)
- use the Module Weight submodule from the [Util](http://drupal.org/project/util) module.